# PHP date() gives wrong time - CentOS server time

Tags: php, date, time, centos

CentOS 6.0. I noticed that the emails sent from ThunderBird client using this server are alright with correct time and everything. But when i send an email using php script, the email is received with -7:05h difference, therefore being received way behind the new emails. The time mysql uses when inserting a new row with ON_UPDATE CUR_TIMESTAMP is correct, but if i use php's date() function to get the time - it's with that -7:05h difference. Looking it up on Google always points out to a wrong timezone, but the php.ini is set to the correct one (America/Denver). When i change the php.ini to Europe/London the date() function prints correct time, but the emails still have the time difference.

```
**hwclock**
Tue 20 Jan 2015 01:22:37 PM GMT  -0.828380 seconds

**echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');**
Tuesday 20th of January 2015 06:07:35 AM
```

Comment: is the server date right?

Comment: Yes 
`date
Tue Jan 20 13:30:28 GMT 2015`

Comment: It was not `13:30 GMT` 1 min ago when you commented that, it was `20:30 GMT`.

Comment: `php: Tuesday 20th of January 2015 06:33:59 AM (America/Denver) || 
date: Tue Jan 20 13:33:46 GMT 2015 || 
hwclock: Tue 20 Jan 2015 01:38:22 PM GMT  -0.515877 seconds`

requested as quick as possible to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server `time` and the `timezone` don't match.

The server time you show is Mountain time (America/Denver) but the timezone is GMT.  GMT is 7 hours ahead of Mountain at the moment.  So set the server time as the current GMT time and keep the GMT timezone, or alternately keep the Mountain time and set the timezone as Mountain time (America/Denver).

I would go with setting the proper GMT time. At `2:00 PM Mountain time` your server clock should be: `Tue 20 Jan 2015 21:00:00 PM GMT`